# DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: no such table Perl

Tags: database, perl, dbi

I created a **SQLite** database and a table named 'COMPANY'.

My intention is to create a module (**Connect.pm**) which blesses the **DataBase Handler ($dbh)** which is the connection to the database, and with the object created, I can call the insert method which is available in Connect.pm.

When I try to insert data in to the database, it is giving me the below **error:**

> DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: no such table: COMPANY at temp.pl
>   line 6.
>   DBD::SQLite::db prepare failed: no such table: COMPANY at
>   temp.pl line 6.

**Connect.pm**

```
package Connect;

use strict;
use DBI;

use Data::Dumper;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $driver = "SQLite";
    my $database = "WEBSITE.db";
    my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname:$database";
    my $userid = "";
    my $password = "";
    my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, { RaiseError => 1}) or die $DBI::errstr;
    my $self = { dbh => $dbh};

    print STDERR "Opened database successfully\n";
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
sub insert {
    my $self = shift;
    my ($id, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $comment) = @_;
    my $sth = $self->{ dbh }->prepare("INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    my $rv = $sth->execute($id, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $comment) or die $DBI::errstr;

    my $value = "Inserted Successfully";
    if($rv < 0){
        $value = $DBI::errstr;
    }
    return $value;
}

1;
```

**temp.pl**

```
use DBI;
use strict;
use Connect;

my $obj = Connect->new();
my $status = $obj->insert("002", "Test", "User", "a\@b.com", "Comment");

$obj->disconenct();
```

---

I can use this program to create the DB and query it, which works.

```
use DBI;
use strict;
my $driver   = "SQLite";
my $database = "WEBSITE.db";
my $dsn      = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
my $userid   = "";
my $password = "";
my $dbh      = DBI->connect( $dsn, $userid, $password, { RaiseError => 1 } ) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $sth      = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
my $rv = $sth->execute( "003", "Test", "User", "a\@b.com", "Test Comment" ) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: Are you sure you created the database correctly? When you use `sqlite3` on the command line, is the table there? You can use the `.tables` command to show all tables in the database from that utility.

Comment: Some guesses: 1) Since you don't specify an absolute path to the database, a new one is being created in your working directory instead of connecting to the existing one. 2) You made a typo in the database and/or table name (e.g. the actual name is `Company`, not `COMPANY`). 3) You never actually created the table successfully.

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
The database is created correctly and there are not mistakes when made in the database name or table name.

Note when I try to insert using the below code (in the next comment) it is working correctly but when I try to use OO model i.e. the above in the issue summary section it is giving me that error,

Comment: use DBI;
 use strict;

 my $driver   = "SQLite";
 my $database = "WEBSITE.db";
 my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
 my $userid = "";
 my $password = "";
 my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password, { RaiseError => 1 }) or die $DBI::errstr;

 my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
 my $rv = $sth->execute("003", "Test", "User", "a\@b.com", "Test Comment") or die $DBI::errstr;

Comment: The DSN in your module is wrong: `"DBI:$driver:dbname:$database"` should be `"DBI:$driver:dbname=$database"` (there should be an equal sign after `dbname`, not a colon).

Comment: Thanks ThisSuitlsBlackNot.... I got this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The DSN in your module is wrong: "DBI:$driver:dbname:$database" should be "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database" (there should be an equal sign after dbname, not a colon). Posted by ThisSuitIsBlackNot Jan 10 at 15:57 is the correct answer...